# Mongodb aggregating large collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So i have a large collection storing messages and i would like to produce time series data from this collection.

Now i had issues with time series data before when i had 10 million records to group by time interval and count / average the values.

`Timestamp => values`

I sort of fixed it by putting all my data into one collection by day so now i have less documents but larger documents. This helped reduce the seek and search time the db needs to find the relevant document. However i am not sure how could i speed up my queries on documents that are not time series. Also i want to search text in this large document, so i have to seek all documents no exepction.

As i said i am storing messages in a single document and the schema looks something like this:

```
Id: string
Author: string
MessageType: string,
Group: string,
Message: string
Votes: number
Date: date
```

I would like to count all the records that contain a word in the message or all the records that has the author Joe. Or sum the votes and so on.
So i would end up with time series data that i can put on a chart.

Now if i have to go through one year data that is about 50 million records. And the query is gona take forever since it has to fetch so many records and filter out the ones i am interested in.

**How could i achieve better performance?**

I have indexing set up on the date and author fields only. Yet my queries are slow and the database is super busy processing one query.

Should i pre aggregate my data somehow, what would be a good way?
Or generate the time series data in a background worker?

Can someone direct me to the right way so i can implement a proper solution that can either reduce the load on the database, or increase query performamce?

What are the best practices for handling such a large collection that contains messages?

How could i segment this kind of data?

Would it be a good idea to set up a replica set and shard the database between multiple machines already?

Any help and input would be appriciated.

Comment: MongoDB recommend to export data to better frameworks like Apache Spark for aggregation if you have large amount of data. MongoDB is not tuned for complex analytics as compared to specialized software.

Comment: @Saleem Source?

Comment: @Saleem could you please explain what benefits would i gain from moving my database to hadoop? Or where did you get this information that its better Why is it better?

Comment: I'd suggest you should be looking into limitation of MongoDB aggregation pipeline (MongoDB documentation) and see if you are not hitting those. Otherwise see if you can overcome those in some specialized software.